# How to change the current build number?

Tags: teamcity

How can I change the current build number to a value specified manually? I'm migrating my project from another build system to TeamCity, and I'd like to make the current build number the same as it was in the old system.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Go to the *General Settings* of the build configuration.
2. Click the orange *Show advanced options*.
3. Set the *Build counter* to your desired value.
4. Set the *Build number format* to `%build.counter%`.

Answer (score 0):

May be helpful
create CMD step with command like this:

```
echo "##teamcity[buildNumber '%major%.%minor%.%build.counter%']"
```